# Can't update Database with EF Code-First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF code-first migrations. I added a new property to my model but it doesn't reflect as a column in the database.

Configuration.cs

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DbContext, DbMigrationsConfiguration<DbContext>>());

using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    context.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

I have already tried the `update-database`. It says no pending migrations.

EDIT:

My EF is a separate Class Library Project. 
There's another Class Library Project that stores all the Models.
And the Main (Startup) Project is an MVC Project.

Where should I include Migrations?

Also, Add-Migrations Initial always gives me EMPTY Up() and Down() methods.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me first of all take backup of your database then delete `migrations` folder in project and delete `__MigrationHistory` table in database 
then run this command

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force
```

then add migration

```
Add-Migration InitialMigration
```

and finally update database with

```
Update-Database
```

Comment: Almost there. Now at least I have code in the Up() and Down() Methods. But I am stuck at "There is already an object named <tablename> in the database."

Comment: try Add-Migration InitialMigration -IgnoreChanges

Comment: and also set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

Comment: I already tried Add-Migration InitialMigration -IgnoreChanges. Then I lose all the code in the Up() and Down() methods and the DB doesn't get updated with the new column. 
Will try with AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

Comment: It doesn't work. I am stuck with "There is already an object named ....... in the database."
"Add-Migration InitialMigration -IgnoreChanges" rescaffolds but nothing happens.

Comment: it gives you this message when you use update-database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138457/discussion-between-usman-and-stylojack-10).

Answer (score 0):

Verbose can fix this problem. In your package manager console run

```
Update-Database –Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>Before executing "Update-Database" command did you run ["Add-Migrations"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_2)?
The Add-Migrations command will generate the necessary migration script to update the database.</del>

Also, do you have a _MigrationsHistory table in your database?

Could you update your code to point to your `MyDbContext` rather than the base `DbContext`? And I believe `DbMigrationsConfiguration<DbContext>>()` should also point to your dbcontext type.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>>())
```

Comment: I had the _MigrationsHistory. I deleted it and ran update-database again.
I also tried with the Add-Migrations command, didn't work. Also, since I already have AutomaticMigrationsEnabled, I shouldn't be forced to use Add-Migrations....right?

Comment: Ah yes, that is correct. You shouldn't need to explicitly run an add-migrations command. The Auto migration should pick it up with the update-database. I am confused by one statement in your code - is your context DbContext or MyDbContext?

Comment: Its MyDbContext.

Answer (score 0):

*Add Your New Model Frst: User Model -id,fname,lname,adress,ect...

*Define in your Application db context the new model as a new set Example : 
 public DbSet Users{ get; set; }

*Create Migration : add-Migration YourMigrationName
*Update Database

Comment: @Billa how and what do u mean exactly ? adding styles to my comment ?

Comment: don't write comments in answer section.